# Can't send form data in Cyrillic

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, character-encoding

I  have a simple contact form (name, email, subject, message) which sends messages to email. I've set client-side validation with jQuery and server-side validation with PHP scripts. I've connected them with Ajax. And it works, but only when I insert data in Latin characters.

When I insert data in Cyrillic, the same form doesn't work. It doesn't send any message. I've searched Internet for similar topics, and YT for some tutorials, but after 4-5 days I still got nothing. Maybe it's something like putting some codes in .htaccess file, but I realy don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic encoding issue. Make sure your form is set up to POST as UTF-8:

```
<form method="post" action="/your/url/" accept-charset="UTF-8">
</form>
```

Also make sure your page is delivered using the correct headers:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Then make sure you are sending the email with correct UT8 headers. I found this code:

```
function mail_utf8($to, $subject = '(No subject)', $message = '', $header = '') {
  $header_ = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
  mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $header_ . $header);
}
```

Source: http://bitprison.net/php_mail_utf-8_subject_and_message

Comment: Is there a common tag for issues like this? Just yesterday someone was having problems submitting forms in Hebrew. We have [utf-8] but the questioner rarely knows what that is.

Comment: I'm not sure :) It's a common question for beginners.

Comment: all set in scripts. its form which sends messages to email, not in mysql db.

Comment: Debug the server logs. You should see the POST request and if data is being sent. It's really unlikely that anything you could enter in a form would stop it from at *least* sending.

Comment: when i look in consol i see that its sending all required data, so im shure its sending. if it doesnt work it woudnt send messages in latin.

Comment: i noted that its form which send data to email adres, not into mysql db

Comment: ok. lets try. where should i put this f-ction in my php. at beging or end or?

Comment: It makes no difference. Just use it instead of the mail function. And please be sure to mark this answer as accepted once it works :)